# Solving inverse function

Tags: functions, inverse-function

> $$f :  \Bbb R \rightarrow \Bbb R $$
>
> $$f^{-1}(2x-7) = x-1, f(a-1) = 5$$
>
> Determine $a$.

The inverse of the function $f^{-1}(2x-7)$ is written as

$$f\biggr (\dfrac{x+7}{2}\biggr ) = x-1$$

Now we have that

$$x+7 = 2(a-1)$$

Solving for x and we get

$$x = 2a-9$$

Plugging $x$ into the function

$$f(a-2) = 2a-9 = 5$$

Solving for $a$

$$2a-9 = 5 \implies 2a = 14 \implies a  = 7$$

Comment: How did you get $f((x+7)/2)=x-1$?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown By taking inverse of given function.

Comment: You need to use $f(x-1) = 2x-7$. $f(x) = y$ becomes $f^{-1}(y) = x$ when dealing with inverses.

Answer (score 3):

I think you are making a mistake when it comes to taking the inverse. If we say that 
$$
f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}
$$
$$
g(x) = 2x-7
$$
then
$$
f^{-1}(2x-7) \equiv f^{-1}\circ g
$$
where you are incorrectly saying that 
$$
f^{-1} \equiv g
$$
now to actually find the values, if 
$$
f^{-1}(2x-7) = x-1 \implies f(x-1) = 2x-7
$$
in order to find the function, we just do a quick observation to see that 
$$
f(x) = 2x - 5 \therefore f(x-1)=2(x-2)-5 = 2x-2-5 = 2x-7
$$
Finally, to solve your problem we find that
$$
f(a-1)=5 \implies 2(a-1)-5 = 5 \implies 2(a-1)=10 \implies a-1 = 5
$$
Therefore $a=6$

Comment: So $f(a-1) = 2a-9 = 2(1)-9 = -7$?

Comment: darn it I made a minor arithmetic error my mistake

Answer (score 2):

You make it too complex. From the given,

$$f^{-1}(2a-7)=a-1\implies2a-7=f(a-1)=5.$$

Answer (score 1):

From the definition of $f^{-1}$, it's clear that $f(x-1) = 2x-7$.  Substitute $x = a$ into $f(a-1) = 5$ to get $2a - 7 = 5.$  Therefore, $a = 6$.